# Android: Let user draw a line from one point to another

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, geometry

I am creating an Android app where useres can draw and write using an active pen on a tablet.
The user can choose between different modes (e.g. pen, eraser, line, circle...) which offers them different tools.
The line and circle tools let the user draw a line/circle with the length/radius and direction where the user draws it. This is working quite well, but every time the user moves the pen another line/circle is drawn and it fills up the screen.

**Image:**
[image: Current result vs. how it should be when drawing from circle center]

**Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
    c.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
}

private float mX, mY, firstX, firstY;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) { //called from MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    firstX = x;
    firstY = y;
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) { //called from MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
    path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
    switch(mode){
        case "line":
            canvas.drawLine(firstX, firstY, x, y, paint);
            break;
        case "circle":
            canvas.drawCircle(firstX, firstY, (Math.abs(firstX-x) + Math.abs(firstY-y))/1.5f, paint); // divisor 1.5 just a rough value
            break;
        default:
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            break;
    }
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
```

Has anyone an idea how I could fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need a `canvas.reset()` before each `drawXxx()`.  If you don't have `invalidate()` before calling `touch_move()`, you may need that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.
I created a new Canvas `animationCanvas` with its own `animationBitmap` for showing the circle while it is drawn.
The final circle is drawn in the method at `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

This is the new `touch_move`:

```
private void touch_move(float x, float y) { //called from MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
    path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
    switch(mode){
        case "line":
            animationCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); // clear previously drawn line (for animation)
            animationCanvas.drawLine(firstX, firstY, x, y, paint);
            break;
        case "circle":
            animationCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); // clear previously drawn circle (for animation)
            animationCanvas.drawCircle(firstX, firstY, (Math.abs(firstX-x) + Math.abs(firstY-y))/1.5f, paint); // divisor 1.5 just a rough value 
            break;
        default:
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            break;
    }    
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
```

Maybe not the best solution  but it works :)